# Smoother fonts in Chromium installed automagically

Tags: unity, 15.04, fonts, chromium

Yesterday evening observed that the Chromium fonts got smoother. I don't really know to explain it, but it feels just better.

The bold text is a little bit bolder that it was in the past and other texts are a little bit smaller.

When I was checking out what happened, my brother said: *Hey, what's going on? It looks like the fonts were changed*. He's using Ubuntu too.

Is this a known change? Does anyone know to explain this?

Here is an example: [my GitHub profile](https://github.com/IonicaBizau)

> [image]
>
> The bold text above *Organizations* looks different than past days. Also, everything looks smoother.

I don't remember I did any important update...

Comment: What a streak you have! :) A little more activity and you'd have been neck and neck with [John Resig](https://github.com/jeresig)!

Comment: It may be due to recent update i think so.

Comment: @vembutech It's strange because I didn't update, or at least I don't remember. Am I the only one who notices this? Could it be a Chromium update?

Comment: @kumar_harsh Hahaha, most of them are [dummy commits](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/github-contributions). Check out [Addy Osmani's contributions](https://github.com/addyosmani). :) Here is the complete story: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9622618

Comment: Oh! You **Cheat** :P LOL! I had seen that generator an year or so ago being mentioned on HN... that's fun! :)